# How to trim a string in Php?

Tags: php

I am looking for only vimeo id 95235223 from the complete link of http://vimeo.com/95235223.
How can I get it in php will trim function work or somthing else. I need help Please.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about forcing people to watch a video instead of reading a manual.

Comment: Have you tried searching for an answer? This is really basic simple php stuff. Something that can be accomplished using a built in function for url parsing.

Comment: What's the problem with your current code? SO generally isn't a code, or regexp writing service...

Answer (score 1):

use [parse_url()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php), like:

```
$url = "http://vimeo.com/95235223";
$parsed = parse_url($url);
$id = str_replace("/", "", $parsed["path"]);
echo $id; //gives 95235223
```

Comment: Thankyou for kind answer, new thing for me. I was doing the same with $rest = substr("http://vimeo.com/95235223", 17). one more thing can I add validation on input type if I require only http://vimeo.com/95235223 in field from user. No other string with this, Can I?